# How do I use a form to change the SQL query to only display registered dates between a specific range?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

The code below is what I have so far, if anyone has any knowledge of how BETWEEN works and could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
    Starting from:<br>
    <input type="date" name="startDate" ><br><br>
    Upto:<br>
    <input type="date" name="uptoDate" ><br><br>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>

<?php
    // I removed the connection details for obvious reasons
    // It does connect and display the data with no problems
    $startingFrom = $_GET[startDate];
    $upto = $_GET[uptoDate];

    // I tried this but it does not seem to work
    // $query = "SELECT * FROM table BETWEEN $startingFrom AND $upto"; 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table><th>Name</th><th>Registered Date</th>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['registered'] . "</td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo "</table>"; 
    mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: You are just missing the `where` there, it should be, `SELECT * FROM 'table' where 'column' between $startingFrom AND $upto`

Comment: Good spot! I changed it but for some reason it still does not work. Could it be because the <input type="date" name="startDate" > is in the format of 06/07/2017 and in my database it is 2017-07-17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning results between two given dates use this code

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('2015-04-03' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-05-28' AS 
DATE);
```

With BETWEEN with dates you need to use CAST() to convert the value to appropriate datatype such as DATE or DATETIME. If you are using BETWEEN with DATETIME cast your value to DATETIME:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('2015-04-03 08:40:09' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2015-05-28 02:50:09' AS DATETIME);
```

As a side note, use MySQL improved extension (mysqli) and you are forgetting to close your input fields which is not a good code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
select * from table where registered >= $startDate and registered <= $endDate;
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it didn't seem to work. Is it because the file this code is on is index.php and the forms action is index.php. I thought that would just simply reload the page?